# Fill table column with UNIQUE in SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite

I have created a table in my database in R:

```
dbExecute(conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dummy' (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          InChikey TEXT UNIQUE,
          InChi TEXT NOT NULL,
          Classification BLOB)")
```

I want to fill the table with a dataframe and the `InChikey` should be `UNIQUE`. I used the following command:

```
dbAppendTable(conn, "dummy", dataset_class)
```

`dataset_class` is a `dataframe`. But im getting the error message:
`Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: dummy.InChikey`

Here are the first 2 rows of my dataset:

| Inchikey | inchi | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IVGJQMIFWABEDB-UHFFFAOYSA-N | InChI=1S/C15H14S2/c1-2-4-12(5-3-1)13-6-8-14(9-7-13)15-16-10-11-17-15/h1-9,15H,10-11H2 | as.raw(c(0x58, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00 |
| BPLWLYWRZQYGSG-UHFFFAOYSA-N | InChI=1S/C13H10F2/c14-13(15)12-8-6-11(7-9-12)10-4-2-1-3-5-10/h1-9,13H | as.raw(c(0x58, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00,0x00, 0x03, 0x00 |

Where is the problem? I have also tried without ID and InChikey as `PRIMARY Key`, but there is the same error.

Comment: Sample data would improve your question.

Comment: I added the first 2 rows of the dataset

Comment: Complete self contained reproducible code and input is required for questions. The library and setup statements are missing.  Input should be shown using `dput`. See the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I have noticed that the input of the `classification`-column was the wrong. I think there is the reason for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The test data and code in the question does not produce the claimed error. Presumably the full data set has duplicates or else you attempted to append dataset_class twice -- if the last statement below is repeated we get the reported error.

```
library(RSQlite)

# test input in reproducible form
dataset_class <- 
structure(list(Inchikey = c("IVGJQMIFWABEDB-UHFFFAOYSA-N", "BPLWLYWRZQYGSG-UHFFFAOYSA-N"
), inchi = c("InChI=1S/C15H14S2/c1-2-4-12(5-3-1)13-6-8-14(9-7-13)15-16-10-11-17-15/h1-9,15H,10-11H2", 
"InChI=1S/C13H10F2/c14-13(15)12-8-6-11(7-9-12)10-4-2-1-3-5-10/h1-9,13H"
), Classification = c("58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 fe", 
"58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 fe 55 54 46 2d"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

conn <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbExecute(conn,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dummy' (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          InChikey TEXT UNIQUE,
          InChi TEXT NOT NULL,
          Classification BLOB)")
## [1] 0
dbAppendTable(conn, "dummy", dataset_class)
## [1] 2
```